# PHPUnit causes undefined method error when --coverage-text (using pcov)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, code-coverage, pcov

I'm trying to get coverage with pcov & PHPUnit for my Laravel project on docker.

I get an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath()` when I add `--coverage-text`.
No error occurs without `--coverage-text`.

What should I do to fix this?

- Case with `--coverage-text`

```
# php -d pcov.enabled=1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text tests/Unit/path/to/my/file
PHPUnit 8.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath() in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:192
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/laravel/app/Some/MyClass.php(5): base_path('vendor/autoload...')
#1 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php(955): include_once('/var/www/html/...')
#2 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage.php(239): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->initializeData()
#3 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(646): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage->start(Object(Tests\Unit\Path\To\My\File))
#4 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(763): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(Object(Tests\Unit\Path\To\My\File))
#5 /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/php in /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 192
```

- Case without `--coverage-text`

```
# php -d pcov.enabled=1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/path/to/my/file
PHPUnit 8.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...........                                                       11 / 11 (100%)

Time: 45.6 seconds, Memory: 64.50 MB

OK (11 tests, 291 assertions)
```

Versions:

- PHP: 7.4.29
- Laravel: 6.20.3
- pcov: 1.0.11
- Xdebug: 3.1.4

I installed pcov with pecl in Dockerfile.

```
RUN yes | pecl install pcov && docker-php-ext-enable pcov
```

Comment: Check `app/Some/MyClass.php` you may be trying to use `base_path` at a point where you're not sure whether or not the framework has been booted properly

Comment: Isn't that same for the case without `--coverage-text`?

Comment: coverage will load all files pre-emptively so some things that normally don't pop up as errors might pop up if you didn't design them with the intention of being loaded out of your expected oreder.

Comment: I use `__DIR__` instead of `base_path()` and the error is now cleared.
Thank you!